# KnockoutObservableArray of type button that has action property doesnt assign action correctly

Tags: loops, dynamic, knockout.js, typescript, click

I'm creating a dynamic popup with dynamic buttons but have a problem when i use its actions.

Button's creation code :

```
openPopup = (buttons: Array<popupButtonsModel>, title?: string, description?: string) => {
    var self = this;
    self.popup().isVisible(false);
    var action: any;
    for (var i: number = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        action = buttons[i].action;
        var button = popupHelper.createPopupButton(buttons[i].text ? buttons[i].text : "Tamam",
            action ? function () { action; self.popup().isVisible(false); } : function () { self.popup().isVisible(false); });
        buttons[i] = button;
    }
    self.popup(popupHelper.createPopup(buttons, title, description));
}
```

When I click button debugger shows me action's value is that (and its undefined)

```
buttons[i].action // should be {alert('Example');}
```

This code shows my buttons correctly but actions are wrong. If i give action undefined to button it works correctly as "function () { self.popup().isVisible(false); });" because of condition.

My view :

```
 <!-- ko if:popup().isVisible-->
<div class="loader-container popup-dialog">
    <div class="panel panel-success modal-dialog">
        <div class="panel-heading">{{popup().title}}</div>
        <div class="panel-body">{{popup().description}}</div>
        <div data-bind="foreach:popup().buttons" class="panel-footer">
            <button data-bind="click:$data.action">{{$data.text}}</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--/ko-->
```

Popup variable at viewmodel is:

```
import popupModel = require('models/popup');
public popup: KnockoutObservable<popupModel> = ko.observable<popupModel>(new popupModel());
```

PopupModel:

```
import popupButtons = require('models/popup-buttons');
class PopupModel {
buttons: KnockoutObservableArray<popupButtons> = ko.observableArray<popupButtons>([]);
isVisible: KnockoutObservable<boolean> = ko.observable(false);
title: KnockoutObservable<string> = ko.observable("");
description: KnockoutObservable<string> = ko.observable("");
}
export = PopupModel;
```

PopupButtonModel:

```
class PopupButtons {
action: any;
text: string;
}
export = PopupButtons;
```

Popup-Helper:

```
import popupButtons = require('models/popup-buttons');
```

import popupModel = require('models/popup');
class PopupManager {
    public static createPopup(buttons: Array, title?: string, description?: string) {
        var popup: popupModel = new popupModel();
        popup.buttons(buttons);
        popup.title(title ? title : "Hata");
        popup.description(description ? description : "İşleminizi şu an gerçekleştiremiyoruz,lütfen tekrar deneyiniz.");
        popup.isVisible(true);
        return popup;
    }

```
public static createPopupButton(text?: string, action?: any) {
    var button: popupButtons = new popupButtons();
    button.text = text;
    button.action = action;
    return button;
}

public static hidePopup(popup: popupModel) {
    popup.isVisible(false);
}
}

export = PopupManager;
```

Comment: Please update the post and create a full example. E.g. it's unclear in your code what `self.popup()` references to. Try to create a [mcve] if possible. In addition, I suggest removing some less relevant tags like "click" and "action" and replacing them by the flavour of JS you're using (Typescript?).

Comment: You're right but they are not important. Popup is a custom class that has action property that type of any and i want to set its value to a click function.

Comment: @Jeroen i've updated. Yes its typescript.